# Update em mais de uma linha

Tags: jquery, mysql, query, sql-update

Estou tentando montar um *update* desse forma:

```
UPDATE cad_vendas SET canal ='9', parceiro ='9' 
WHERE cpf_vendedor ='CPF_VENDEDOR' and status_proposta_producao ='90'
and forma_pagamento <> '';
```

porém ele não aceita se eu não passo o `id` da linha e são varias linhas.

Alguém têm alguma solução onde eu consiga dar *uptade* em N linhas?

Comment: Que erro retorna?

Comment: Qual a relação com a tag `jQuery`? Tem certeza que esta *query* é válida? No caso, existe registros que satisfazem as 3 condições do `where`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ele faz isso por segurança, para evitar que você faça um update errado em todo o banco, por exemplo.

Adicione a informação da chave que ele esta solicitando.

Por exemplo:

```
UPDATE cad_vendas SET canal ='9', parceiro ='9' 
WHERE cpf_vendedor ='CPF_VENDEDOR' and status_proposta_producao ='90'
and forma_pagamento <> '' and id > 10 and id < 30;
```

ou

```
UPDATE cad_vendas SET canal ='9', parceiro ='9' 
WHERE cpf_vendedor ='CPF_VENDEDOR' and status_proposta_producao ='90'
and forma_pagamento <> '' and id in (10,20,30,40,50 )
```

Comment: Obrigado Reginaldo Rigo, eu não realmente não tinha pensado nisso!
Funcionou certinho, obrigado!